# best way to replace first and last character of a row in a file

Tags: c#

i have a file that looks like this:

```
"sdfkhsdf,sdfgsg,sdfsdf,sdsdf"
"sdfsdf,"43534",sdfsdf,24234,sfddsf"
"efsdf,234234,sdfsdf,234234,sadfsdf"
```

i need to remove the FIRST and LAST character of every row in the file (i need to remove the first double quote and the last double quote). please note that the data MAY have quotes inside of it, but the first and last quotes are definitely not needed.

what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: if you just need to do this once, any good editor can do it real quick. search `^"(.+)"$`. replace `\1` (or `$1` depending on editor)

Comment: If this is a one time task, normally I like to use sed or visual studio's find-replace

Comment: @PaulPhillips how can i use visual studio to do find replace for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [string.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9) if you don't have lines like: `""sdfsdf", 43534,sdfsdf,24234,"sfddsf""`

```
line.Trim('"');
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is truely only first and last character, I'd do something like:

```
    using (var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename))
    {
        using (var outfile = System.IO.File.CreateText(newfilename))
        {
            foreach (var line in text)
            {
                if (line.Length > 2)
                    outfile.WriteLine(line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2));
                else
                    outfile.WriteLine(line);
            }
            outfile.Flush();
        }
    }
```

and yes, Trim(...) is better in this case.

Comment: This doesn't compile. File.ReadAllLines returns string[] which does not implement IDisposable, and you can't use it's return type in a using statement.

Be careful, this code also seems to assume CRLF line endings.